# C# Assembly cast to type fails

Tags: c#, reflection

There is my sample code

```
public interface ICommonInterface
{
    Task<T> SomeMethod<T>(string params) where T : new();
}

public class ExternalAssembly : ICommonInterface
{
   public ExternalAssembly(string params) {...}
   public async Task<T> SomeMethod<T>(string params) where T : new() {...}
}
```

So I am loading the assembly from another project which also references `ICommonInterface`. I have the following code, which fails at the last step

```
object assemblyInstance;
Assembly assembly;
assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFile);
Type type = assembly.GetType("Namespace.ExternalAssembly");
assemblyInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new[] { params });

var myClass = (assemblyInstance as ICommonInterface);
```

The problem is that `myClass` is null

The previous version of the code was working flawlessly, here it is (only interface was different)

```
public interface ICommonInterface
{
    Task<SomeClass> SomeMethod(string params);
}

public class ExternalAssembly : ICommonInterface
{
   public ExternalAssembly(string params) {...}
   public async Task<SomeClass> SomeMethod(string params) {...}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure both projects have been recompiled with the latest version of `ICommonInterface`? You can use a direct cast to have a more explicit error: `var myClass = (ICommonInterface)assemblyInstance;`

Comment: What is the result of `assemblyInstance`?

Comment: To debug this print out `assemblyInstance.GetType()` and check the full type name and assembly. Compare that to `typeof(ICommonInterface)`.

Comment: For this to work, both the assembly as well as your code project loading that assembly need to reference `ICommonInterface` from the **same** assembly/class library. If your assembly contains a declaration for `ICommonInterface` and your main code project also contains a declaration for `ICommonInterface`, then those are two distinct and separate interfaces (even when their implementation would be identical). They would not be the same and could not be cast from one to the other.

Comment: @KevinGosse That was a great advice man. Thank you, it solved my problem !

Comment: Unless you know exactly what you are doing, you should never use `Assembly.LoadFile`, and from the question I can more or less guess that you are not exactly sure `Assembly.LoadFile` is what you want

Comment: @EmrahSüngü so what's the alternative ?

Comment: Assembly.Load should be your priority then LoadFrom